# SSH over hotspot network?

Tags: networking, ssh, pi-zero-w

I have looked through here a bit and seem to have a unique situation I'm trying to address.

I have an iphone with my hotspot enabled. I connect to the hotspot with a raspberry pi zero w over wifi. I then connect via usb cable to my desktop pc and gain access to the network via usb. When I attempt to SSH into the pi with my pc, I cannot connect.

Is there an issue I am unaware of regarding trying to connect my pc to my pi?

Comment: iOS doesn't block WiFi clients from seeing each other on a "WiFi" network, but you mentioned you are connected a computer via USB and not via WiFi.  Can you elaborate?  Are you using USB to provide network access to the computer via your phone's cellular radio and also trying to join the Pi Zero via WiFi to the same cellular radio?  If so, this is a little different than just having two clients on the same WiFi Personal Hotspot at the same time.

Comment: Yes, as you described - that is my exact setup. I tried to explain that in the initial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't connect form one device to another through the iPhone hotspot :
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194842/iphone-is-the-hotspot-isolated-can-you-see-other-devices
So you might be out of luck with this setup.

Comment: I have regularly used the iOS "Personal Hotspot" to create a LAN between computers.  I've routinely done this to build demos (work) when I'm in locations that don't otherwise have a LAN that I can use.  I just re-tested this feature this morning (just to make sure it hasn't changed -- it has not changed).  Multiple clients can directly communicate if they are on the same iOS Personal Hotspot network (it does not impose "WiFi isolation").  I'm wondering if there was some long-ago iOS version that imposed isolation, but I've been doing this for years.  (Is it possibly carrier-dependent?)

Comment: You might be right, at least one other person on the other answer said that he succeed in doing this.
However, without more information about the iOS version, I tend to think that this is the cause of the trouble that OP experiments. It might not be the general case.
Also, note that he does not directly access the WiFi, but communicate with the iPhone via USB, which is not exactly the same thing.